# I don't get why this isn't creating a text file

Tags: php, html

I'm suppose to create a short quiz and when you hit submit it takes you to a results page that shows the person's name, score, correct answers to the questions, time, and date and it also saves that data and keeps building the history of people who took the test. Here's what I have and I just don't know why it isn't working. I'm really new to PHP so I know I'm probably doing something stupid.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Homework 1CD: Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homework1a.css" />
</head>
<body class="berry">
    <h1>Quiz!</h1>
    <form action = "homework1cd.php" method = "POST">
        <p>
        <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="fname">
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="dropdown">How many toes does the average cat have?
        </label>
        <br>
            <select id="dropdown" name="question1">
                <option value="A" name="question1">18</option>
                <option value="B" name="question1">24</option>
                <option value="C" name="question1">56</option>
                <option value="D" name="question1">20</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        
        <p>Cats are the only mammals who don't taste sweetness. True/False
        <br>
            <input type="radio" id="radio" name="question2" value="A">
                <label for="question2>A">True</label>
                <br>
            <input type="radio" id="radio" name="question2" value="B">
                <label for="question2>B">False</label>
        
        </p>
        
        <p>
        <label for="checkbox" name="question3">Check all that are breeds of cat:</label>
        <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="question3" value="A">
            <label for="question3>A">BooBoo</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="question3" value="B">
            <label for="question3>B">Fluffy Bottom</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="question3" value="C">
            <label for="question3>C">Lil Cutie</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="question3" value="D">
            <label for="question3>D">Sphynx</label>
        </p>
        
        <p>Cats are farsighted. True/False
        <br>
            <input type="radio" id="radio" name="question4" value="A">
                <label for="question4>A">True</label>
                <br>
            <input type="radio" id="radio" name="question4" value="B">
                <label for="question4>B">False</label>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="dropdown">How many times their own body length can cats jump?</label>
        <br>
            <select id="dropdown" name="question5">
                <option value="A" name="question5">10x</option>
                <option value="B" name="question5">6x</option>
                <option value="C" name="question5">2x</option>
                <option value="D" name="question5">100x</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
        </p>
    </form>
    
<?php
//date and time
echo "<p>Today is " . date("m/d/y. "), "</p>";
echo "<p>The time is " . date("h:i."), "</p>";

//get the person's answers
$answer1 = $_POST['question1'];
$answer2 = $_POST['question2'];
$answer3 = $_POST['question3'];
$answer4 = $_POST['question4'];
$answer5 = $_POST['question5'];

//set up for correct answers
$correct_answer = 0;

//count the correctly answered questions 
if ($answer1 == "A") { $correct_answer++; }
if ($answer2 == "A") { $correct_answer++; }
if ($answer3 == "D") { $correct_answer++; }
if ($answer4 == "A") { $correct_answer++; }
if ($answer5 == "B") { $correct_answer++; }

//create variable for name, date, and time
if ($_POST['fname']){
    $name = $_POST['fname'];
    $text = $name . ";";
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $time = $_POST['time']; 
}

//write txt file for stored results
$myfile = fopen("results.txt", "a");

fwrite($myfile, $name);
fwrite($myfile, $correct_answer);
fwrite($myfile, $answer1);
fwrite($myfile, $answer2);
fwrite($myfile, $answer3);
fwrite($myfile, $answer4);
fwrite($myfile, $answer5);
fwrite($myfile, $time);
fwrite($myfile, $date);
fclose("results.txt");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>results</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th name="fname">Name</th>
        <th name="correct_answer">Score</th>
        <th name="answer1">Question1</th>
        <th name="answer2">Question2</th>
        <th name="answer3">Question3</th>
        <th name="answer4">Question4</th>
        <th name="answer5">Question5</th>
        <th name="time">Time</th>
        <th name="date">Date</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
//call to get file contents
$contents = file_get_contents ("results.txt");
$resultset = explode(";", $contents);
foreach($resultset as $name) {
    echo $name;
    echo $correct_answer;
    echo $answer1;
    echo $answer2;
    echo $answer3; 
    echo $answer4;
    echo $answer5;
    echo $time;
    echo $date;
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: It looks like you have 2 pages in one script file. Is that the case

Comment: They're two separate pages. The  second part is results.php to retrieve the text file. the first bit is the page where the information is put in

Comment: Start by defining exactly what _"it isn't working"_ actually means. Are you seeing error messages? Does the output match what you expect?

Comment: So I ran the HTML through a validator and the PHP.  Both said that there were no syntax issues. When I click on the submit button nothing happens.  I would like when I hit the submit button for the user to then be taken to a results page that stores results in a txt file. I'm not seeing any error messages, just nothing happens

Comment: Hi there, if you have the chance, could you label which code portion relates to the file named `homework1cd.php`? The form action in the above code portion seems to point to that. Maybe there needs to be some sort of check to see if the form has been submitted yet or not?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [PHP's fopen function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) it should return `false` upon error, and produce a warning.

You can check the return value directly in the code:

```php
$myfile = fopen("results.txt", "a");
if (!$myfile) {
  echo("file could not be created");
}
```

But to check the exact error message, you have to look at the webpage you created to check for a warning logs, or in your server's logs.

It is possible that the server does not allow files to be created by HTTP clients.
Make sure to write the file to a safe directory, with the proper permissions.